# Undo Manager is nil --- Why?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsundomanager

Why is `[self undoManager]` zero in a child window, in a doc-based app?

Should it not refer to the undo manager of its parent window? In the parent window, I get an actual address for the undo manager!

Comment: And `self` here is a subclass of `NSDocument`?

Comment: `self` is subclassed from `NSWindowController`; does it only work when subclassed from `NSDocument`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `undoManager`is not a member of NSWindowController.
This is just a NSDocument "feature".

An excerpt from the NSDocument docs :
... A document manages its window’s edited status and is set up to perform undo and redo operations. ....

Section "Subclassing NSDocument":

.... Subclasses are also responsible for the creation of the window controllers that manage document windows and for the implementation of undo and redo. ....

The code you've written won't work on other strongly typed languages because you would send a message to an object that doesn't exist. I'm pretty sure you should have a compiler warning here.

Hope this helps,

best,

Flo

Comment: Thanks, that does help. The question remains how I fix it. I need a way to determine that my child window belongs to the document pointed at by **X**. How would I get **X**, if the window is opened through the `appController`?

Comment: I reimplemented `showWindow:sender`, picking up the document pointer (which should be "sender"), then calling `[super showWindow]`. Why do It get this error: *2012-06-27 14:39:59.315 myApp[32268:403] +[AppController _autosavesInPlace]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x105c70790*?

Comment: Please IGNORE previous comment: the "sender" is the appController, not the parent document. So, how would I get a pointer to the *NSDocument*?

Comment: I am now using a command `[newWindow setUndoManager:[self undoManager]]` right after initializing *newWindow*. Of course I defined an undoManager property in the newWindow. The only issue is that I can only undo if the *original* window is active. There must be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

Flo's answer was a good starting point. Some time later, it turns out that the responder chain is somehow acting up (or, it may be me :-) ).

The child window, controlled by `NSWindowController`, should automatically (??) have a *document* property so that `[self document]` returns the document associated with this window. It's easy to pull the Undo manager from that.

However, in my application (and in a small testing app, too) this document is not set. When I set it manually from within the document (`[newWindow setDocument:self]`), everything works: registering the undo/redo actions, the menu bar, etc.

Comment: Is your question now answered?

Comment: Yes. But a new question follows: *why* did the responder chain get messed up? Am I wrong in assuming that it should go back to the originating document? If so, why? If not, what else is going on?